# How do I find which headers I want to use in my project?

Tags: python

Hello I decided to use steams web api key and I have some problems.

As i check every guide on web api I can't understand 1 thing. How do I find the right headers and params for my project. I would like to retrive information about items in players inventory about which you can read about on https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetPlayerItems

I 've found whole url that makes this request

http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_/GetPlayerItems/v0001/

but I was wondering if there's a way to send it using python requests more like this.

(The code is not mine it's just an example)
~~

```
import requests  
  headers = {     'user-agent': USER_AGENT }  
  payload = {         
                  'api_key': API_KEY,       
                  'method': 'chart.gettopartists',     
                  'format': 'json'  
            }   
 r=requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/', headers=headers, params=payload) r.status_code
```

Where am I supposed to use the WebAPI/GetPlayerItems line?

Comment: _How do I find the right headers and params for my project._ What do you mean by _right_ ?

Comment: I mean the headers I need to send a specific request like to get all items in my inventory using the link to article I provided

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the API URL in the first parameter of the get request.

```
import requests  
headers = {     'user-agent': USER_AGENT }  
payload = {         
              'api_key': API_KEY,       
              'method': 'chart.gettopartists',     
              'format': 'json'  
        }   
 r=requests.get('API_URL_GOES_HERE', headers=headers, 
 params=payload)
```